# Calculate nasty integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

In physics I ran into some nasty integrals involving characteristic functions $\chi$.

The ones are given by

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left(E - \frac{p^2}{2m}-\frac{q^2 \omega^2}{2} \right)^{n-1} \chi_{[0,E]} \left( \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{q^2 \omega^2}{2} \right) \frac{p^2}{2m} dq dp,$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left(E - \frac{p^2}{2m}-\frac{q^2 \omega^2}{2} \right)^{n-1} \chi_{[0,E]} \left( \frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{q^2 \omega^2}{2} \right) \frac{q^2 \omega^2}{2}  dq dp,$$

where all constants are positive(!).

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I suggest to first change variables via $x = p/\sqrt{2m}$, $y=q\omega/\sqrt{2}$. Then one possibility could be to introduce polar coordinates.

Comment: Further explanation: The \chi_M(x)$ is $1$ if $x\in M$ and $0$ otherwise. In polar coordinates ($r =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$) this will correspond to an integration over $0\leq r\leq \sqrt{E}$ (and arbitrary argument $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$).

Comment: Not sure I understand the characteristic function in this context. You are integrating over $\mathbb{R}^2$, so what does $\chi_{[0, E]}$ mean?

Comment: this function takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ and spits out either 0 or 1. i am not sure, if I see your problem

Comment: @MarkFantini: The argument of $\chi_E$ is the **real quantity** $x^2 + y^2$ (after te change of variables proposed above). Hence there is no conflict between $[0,E]\subset \Bbb{R}$, but integrating over $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I understand now. Thank you.